# Populate DropDown and Get Selected Value From Database

Tags: php

I have the code to select the values from a database for populating my drop down list. But my question is if I stored the value of what the user selected in another database, how would I go about pulling that back out and making that the selected choice.

```
<select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1">

<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    print '<option id="'.$options[$i]["ID"].'" value="'.$options[$i]["Value"].'">'.$options[$i]["Name"].'</option>'."\n";
}
?>
</select>
```

So the users stored value is lets say red. How would I make red the selected value as it populates my drop down list?

Thanks e

Comment: you want to make the select box sticky, is that correct? meaning that if one value is selected and the user posts the page, when it returns the previous value is still selected?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1">

<?php
$selected = "red";

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    if ($options[$i]['Value'] == $selected) {
        print '<option selected="selected" id="'.$options[$i]["ID"].'" value="'.$options[$i]["Value"].'">'.$options[$i]["Name"].'</option>'."\n";
    } else {
        print '<option id="'.$options[$i]["ID"].'" value="'.$options[$i]["Value"].'">'.$options[$i]["Name"].'</option>'."\n";
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

On each element test the value. If the value is selected, print 'selected'.

```
<select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1">
<?php
$selected = 'red';// obviously replace with DB value.
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    // start as normal
    print '<option id="'.$options[$i]["ID"].'" value="'.$options[$i]["Value"].'"';

    // if this one is selected, add 'selected' to the tag.
    // NOTE: booleans in HTML do not need to have an attribute value.
    // so selected="selected" is not necessary here.
    if( $options[$i]["Value"] == $selected ) print ' selected';

    // finish as normal
    print '>'.$options[$i]["Name"].'</option>'."\n";
}
?>
</select>
```

As a side note: if you use foreach it will make for smaller, more compact, and often faster code:

```
//this assumes that you want to iterate the whole options array
foreach( $options as $option )
{
    print '<option id="'.$option["ID"].'" value="'.$option["Value"].'"';
    if( $option["Value"] == $selected ) print ' selected';
    print '>'.$option["Name"].'</option>'."\n";
}
```