# Pulling Data in PHP from SQL Server

Tags: php, sql

I have an issue with my script somewhere but do not know exactly where it is incorrect.  Here is the code:

```
<title>Log</title>
</head>

<h1> Log </h1>

<form method="get" action="getlog.php"> 

<table width="300" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td> Forte ID:</td>
    <td><select id="ForteID" name="ForteID">                    
                    <option value="nc4682">nc4682</option>
                    <option value="bs1441">bs1441</option>
                    <option value="sp3212">sp3212</option>                 
        </select></td>
  </tr>
</table>

 <input type="submit" name="getLog" value="Get Log">
 </form> 

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php
/*print_r($_POST);*/
$serverName = 'SRB-Nick_Desktop\SQLEXPRESS';
$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'cslogs', 'UID'=>'cslogslogin', 'PWD'=>'123456');
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

$query = 'SELECT    ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC,     Notes from logs';

$result = sqlsrv_query($connection,$query);

if (!$result) 
{
    $message = 'ERROR: ' . sqlsrv_errors();
    return $message;
}
else
{
    $i = 0;
    echo '<html><body><table><tr>';
    while ($i < sqlsrv_num_rows($result))
    {
        $meta = sqlsrv_fetch($result, $i);
        echo '<td>' . $meta->name . '</td>';
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    while ( ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))) 
    {
        $count = count($row);
        $y = 0;
        echo '<tr>';
        while ($y < $count)
        {
        $c_row = current($row);
        echo '<td>' . $c_row . '</td>';
        next($row);
        $y = $y + 1;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt ($result);

echo '</table></body></html>';
}
sqlsrv_close( $connection);
?>
```

And this is what I get in result, no matter what is selected in the drop down box and hit the button get log.

nc4682  nc4682  Save    Save    asdf    asdf    fdas    fdas    1   1   cc  cc  asdf    asdf
bs1441  bs1441  LOC LOC AN00336862  AN00336862  None    None    0   0   ach ach Backout Backout
nc4682  nc4682  Save    Save    AN00336862  AN00336862  easdf   easdf   2   2   ach ach asdf    asdf
sp3212  sp3212  Sale    Sale    NCXXXXXX1   NCXXXXXX1   none    none    1   1   cc  cc  asdfasdfasdf    asdfasdfasdf

Each column is duplicated.  There are supposed to be 7 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only show the results from the drop down list you would append something like 
    WHERE ForteID = {$_GET['ForteID']}
to the end of your SQL statement.

Comment: That did not work.  Gives me error:  unexpected T_STRING.  This is where I put it and I always thought that is what I would put:  $query = 'SELECT ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC, Notes from logs
   WHERE ForteID = {$_GET['ForteID']} ';

Comment: Totally my bad, this'll work: $query = 'SELECT ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC, Notes FROM logs WHERE ForteID = ' . $_GET["ForteID"];

Comment: Getting closer I think but now getting this: Undefined index: ForteID in C:\wamp\www\cslogs\getlog.php on line 37

Comment: You'll want to wrap it in an if to see if the variable exists. Something like: if ($_GET['ForteID']) $query = 'SELECT ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC, Notes from logs WHERE ForteID = ' . $_GET['ForteID'];

Comment: It is not pulling out the data now.

Comment: Put an "echo $query;" inside the IF loop, and an "echo $_GET['ForteID'];" just before the IF loop and see if it is giving you the values correctly.

Comment: It displays the correct selection when I hit the submit button!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that I can help much more from here, I have zero experience with MSSQL. Is there an equivalent of like PHPMYADMIN that you can run SQL queries against? I always copy my echo of $query into phpMyAdmin and run it there to make sure my syntax is not incorrect.

Comment: Ok I think I know what needs to happen.  This is what the echo prints out:  SELECT ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC, Notes from cslogs.dbo.logs WHERE ForteID = bs1441  ,but it needs to have apostraphes around the bs1441 so like this 'bs1441'.   how do I get that

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I figured out a way for the apostrophes to get there.  In my form the values I added apostrophes in front and the end of it so the sql statement will have the apostrophes it needs.  If there is a better way to do it that would be great to know.  But thanks again for the help.  Now the next thing for me to tackle is to have the drop down list pull the list from my sql database.  haha

Comment: Well, I don't want to carry on too long in the discussion, but basically what you'll do is have your select tag start, then do a while loop that returns all results surrounded by option tags, then close your select tag after the loop, something like: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853290/populate-dropdown-and-get-selected-value-from-database) From a quick search

Answer (score 0):

`sqlsrv_fetch_array()` returns both a numeric array and an associative array by default.

Try specifying only one type of array

`while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ))`

To use your dropdpwn in the query.

```
$query = 'SELECT    ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC,     Notes FROM logs WHERE ForteID =' . $_GET['ForteID'];
```

Please be aware that without sanitizing the $_GET variable this query is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Wow that is awesome!!!  Now do you know if is as easy as you just did to make it where it only shows results with the selection in the drop down menu from the form?

Comment: As I am not getting the error anymore, it is also not pulling any records.  As for the vulnerability, it is just an in house thing, nothing that is going onto the web.